# How to transform a WebService call that is using behaviours?

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services, asp.net-1.1, behavior

We have some really old code that calls WebServices using behaviours (webservice.htc), and we are having some strange problems... since they've been deprecated a long time ago, I want to change the call.

What's the correct way of doing it? It's ASP.NET 1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to generate a proxy class using wsdl.exe. Then just use the web service as you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not 100% sure what the Web Service behavior does, I recall it allows client-side script to call Web Services, which would make AJAX it's contemporary replacement.

Since you're using .NET 1.1 how about using [Ajax.NET Professional](http://www.ajaxpro.info) to connect to the web services?